# can anyone help with this trying to install magento 1.5.1.0 and keep getting this error meassge?

Tags: magento

I'm doing a fresh install of magento 1.5.1.0 ce , i download it ok and start the install wizard but get this error message  after the loaclization page :

There has been an error processing your request

Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 2101428511

The thing is i have installed magento from the same zip file to the same local server before but had to unistall it for other reasons , now struggling to re-install i have also tried the downloader.php and get the same problem.

Any ideas ?

I always find stackoverflow the best place for answers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have your project directories with write permission.

You can find the error details at: /www/yourproject/var/report/2101428511

Comment: If this is only localhost (security reasons) rename project/errors/local.xml.sample to local.xml
this way you will see actual error on screen.

Comment: Thanks thats helped , i think it is because i have an underscore in my file/domain name ie: shushu_magento ?

Comment: sorry for the delay in replying